# Clean syntax for awaiting two async let returning type void

Tags: swift

Two async functions in Swift which should be started at the same time and then awaited at some point. I have found already a solution but I am not 100 percent happy with the syntax. I want to write following code in a cleaner syntax if possible.

1. I know I could use task group
2. For some reason I need to explicitly declare the return type even though it is clear from the func return type.

```swift
Task {
    async let task1: () = task1()
    async let task2: () = task2()
    
    _ = await [task1, task2]
}

func task1() async { }
func task2() async { }
```

Comment: What is a "cleaner" syntax? Is it just the explicit types of `()`  that you don't like?

Comment: And if you know you can use a task group, why not just use that?

Comment: TaskGroup is imo intended for a dynamic range of tasks and not for two hard coded ones. And yes I would like to get rid of the explicit definition of the type `()` as well as the `_ =` where I already found out that I can also write `await task1 await task2`

Comment: This seems to me to be a silly thing to worry about. The "problem" is that `async let` is a form of `let` — you have to assign something to something, and Swift warns when you assign Void to something along with type inference. If having to say `()` really bothers you so much, you'd be better off making `task1` and `task2` return something such as an Int just for the sake of getting a type inference without a warning.

Comment: I know that this is complaining on a really high level. I was just wondering if there is a type inferred way - if not I am ok with that as well.

Comment: Doesn't solve the broader problem, but btw: You can also use a tuple in `_ = await (task1, task2)`, instead of an Array.

Answer (score 2):

The current code you have is perfectly acceptable (IMO), but I do think a `TaskGroup` better expresses your intent.

```swift
await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { taskGroup in
    taskGroup.addTask { await task1() }
    taskGroup.addTask { await task2() }

    // or alternatively:
    // taskGroup.addTask(operation: task1)
    // taskGroup.addTask(operation: task2)
}
```

By the way, you need your `task1`/`task2` functions to be marked `@Sendable` to pass them between tasks, regardless of which approach you end up taking.

> TaskGroup is imo intended for a dynamic range of tasks and not for two hard coded ones.

It certainly can handle dynamic numbers of tasks, but it's perfectly fine for fixed numbers of tasks. In fact, the structured concurrency syntax you're using is really just syntactic sugar that constructs TaskGroups under the hood.

> For some reason I need to explicitly declare the return type even though it is clear from the func return type

Most assignments of a `Void` (`()`) result into a variable are likely unintentional, so this is [syntactic salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar#Syntactic_salt) to confirm that it really is your intention. The genuine need to do that is pretty rare and unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like that:

```swift
Task {
    await (task1(), task2())
}
```

No need to have `async let` variables at all. Code will start both async functions and await for result from both of them.

Comment: This isn’t quite the same, as it’ll run the tasks sequentially instead of concurrently.

Comment: Yep, rechecked it. So, it's either groups or syntax from the code in the Question.